# How to use Jquery document.on() on elements that are pulled in via Ajax?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I have a Jquery Mobile shell page, which I'm loading a form into using Ajax. The form has some checkboxes, which I need to bind to.

Oddly, I can get it to work setting the listener directly on the button like so:

```
$('input[name="ohneiln"]').on('change', function() {
   alert("hello");
   });
```

But when I'm trying to set the listener to `$(document)` and delegate to the `checkbox`, the listener never fires:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="ohneiln"]', function() {
   alert("hello");
});
```

**Question:**
What is the correct way to set an event binding for "dynamic" elements being loaded in via Ajax using `$(document).on()`? Is this not possible for `change` events or why am I running into troubles?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your second syntax seems fine and should work for dynamic elements, the problem is somewhere else maybe.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7rDDA/

Comment: @Esailija - but your input is there when the page loads. Mine is not, it's being pulled in via Ajax after the user does some stuff

Comment: @frequent: Works for me with the input loaded via AJAX.  http://jsfiddle.net/7rDDA/1/

Comment: @frequent and your second code is for those element, pulled via ajax

Comment: It works for checkboxes too, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7rDDA/4/

Comment: @frequent that doesn't make any difference with event delegation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way the `.on()` method works changes according to how you use it. In your first example the `.on()` method behaves similar to `bind` and will only work on elements that already exist.

The second example behaves like `.live()` or `delegate()` in many ways. And will work for elements that are added later.

Read the docs for a detailed explanation http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. Guess I'm sticking with the first version then.

Comment: I think you got the first and second example mixed up.  The 1st is "direct", the 2nd is "delegated".

Comment: I wonder if op got it mixed up like i did my explanation. Maybe thats why my explanation made sense lol. I corrected the explanation.

Comment: instead of $(document), wouldn't you want to attach .on to the closest parent id anyways, for performance?