# jQuery .on() click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a website which displays events onto a map. When the user hovers over an event pushpin, a tooltip info window displays and gives event info. When the user clicks the pushpin, they should be zoomed closer to the event.

I have this functionality working on all browsers except Firefox. For some reason the click event for each pushpin div does not fire. This is especially odd, because the mouseover event fires without a problem. I'm not seeing any errors either.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.pushpin', function () {
  alert('Detected a click!');
});


$(document).on('mouseover', 'div.pushpin', function () {
  // Displays tooltip
});
```

Here is my website: http://www.raveradar.com/qa

You can compare how it works in Chrome against Firefox to see the issue.

I tried to isolate the problem by creating a jsFiddle. But the click event fires without a problem in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acraswell/9TxQg/4/

At this point I could really use a second pair of eyes to check my work.

**EDIT:**
I've just realized that if you disable the "position: fixed;" CSS property on the "pushpin-icon" image, suddenly clicking the icon works fine.

**EDIT 2:**
I've managed to resolve the issue, please see my solution below. I will award the answer to anyone who can explain why the original code was broken to begin with since that was the real question.

Comment: jsfiddler dosnt show the code, please fix it

Comment: I can see the local map on your website, obviously no event pushpins available locally. Please specify the Country/Location on map where you have created your test pushpins. Edit: I opened in firefox, and it opened the right location with event pushpins. That didn't happen on chrome.

Comment: Fixed the jsFiddle. For location, look at Seattle, WA. I forgot it was detecting location. There should be about 170 pushpins spread throughout the US.

Comment: your site works as you describe on my firefox, only *sometimes* the event wont fire. Maybe an overlaying invisible element?

Comment: Okay, I've just noticed that if I click on the red "alert" circle which says how many events are in the pushpin cluster, the click event registers correctly... but clicking on the pushpin icon doesn't work.

There shouldn't be any overlaying elements, notice that the mouseover event fires without a problem.

Comment: Wprks for me, firefox 17.0.1, linux

Comment: Hmmm, I'm running 17.0.1 as well and it isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried it without attaching mouseover event? I think jsFiddle is working because that doesn't have a real mouseover event like in your website.

Comment: Maybe you know this already but when I look in Chrome, your .pushpin elements all have 0 height... how are they capturing any events at all?

Comment: @Stuart, how did you figure out it? they don't have 0 height, they have two children elements.

Comment: @Stuart, I'm seeing that now as well. And that makes me wonder how it's capturing events in Chrome to begin with...

Comment: @ocanal I mean the height according to Computed Style in Chrome's Developer Tools. But you're right, they have children elements which do have height and that is how they are picking up the mouse over / click events. I would check whether those children elements are being positioned correctly across browsers (they have relative or fixed positioning) and don't perhaps have their own event handlers interfering with the handlers on the `.pushpin` elements.

Comment: Looking on Firefox it *sometimes* seems to work only when I click on the middle but not on the edges (which are made of padding) of the alert circles, so I wonder if there's some peculiarity in how FF treats clicks on padded elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting I resolved the issue. Here are the steps I took:

1) As previously mentioned, removing the `position: fixed` attribute on the `.pushpin-icon` image seemed to allow the click event to be triggered.

2) I changed the `.pushpin-icon` 'img' tag to a `div`, and used the 'background-image' CSS property to set the icon image.

3) With the `position: fixed;` property gone, I had to adjust the relative positions of the `.pushpin` children.

Now it seems to work just fine. I'm still not sure why it wasn't working to begin with, which was the real question. I'll award the answer to anyone who can figure out why.

See the changes on the site: http://www.raveradar.com/qa

A message is logged to the console upon clicking any pushpin.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

I think i've narrow it down for you 
in your css  i noticed you used `pointer-events: all;` which according to mozilla is experimental

> Warning: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is
>   experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft
>   specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to
>   CSS4.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

i think that is what's causing the issue in Firefox remove them from you're css and inline css and try it

---

the click events workes only if you clicked on the numbers not the imag
try binding the click event on the image instead of the div.pushpin

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.pushpin-icon', function () {
  alert('Detected a click!');
});


$(document).on('mouseover', 'div.pushpin', function () {
  // Displays tooltip
});
```

if both events are doing the same you can combine events in on

```
   $(document).on('click mouseover', 'img.pushpin-icon', function () {
      alert('Detected a click!');
    });
```

Comment: Tried binding the click event to "img.pushpin-icon" with no result. It's currently bound to the container div which works for all other browsers. I don't understand while it wouldn't in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the specific click() function instead of the on() function?

```
$("img.pushpin-icon").click(function(){alert("clicky");});
```

EDIT: use "pushpin-icon", not pushpin

Comment: The pushpins div elements are added dynamically via an AJAX call after the DOM is already loaded. The specific click() function won't work. But yeah, I double checked to make sure :/

Comment: I somehow couldn't comment on your question above.

Comment: did you notice that your <img> tag is somehow broken?
<img class="pushpin-icon" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/277005_183138995162066_953515647_q.jpg" alt''="">
see the 'alt' part

Comment: Tried "img.pushpin-icon" as well both with .click() and .on(), no luck. I need to use the .on() function so that it binds to all future elements added tot he DOM.

Comment: ok, now I figured out why it's **not** working, however no solution:
on every mouseover on a pushpin, it is somehow reloaded, removing the pushpin from the dom tree and re-inserting a new one instead (probably for mouseover color changes or the like). So the newly inserted pushpin doesn't have a click handler yet, because it was added to the dom tree after you called $(...).on() - that's the problem

Comment: No, that shouldn't be the problem because the .on() method continually scans for new elements added to the DOM dynamically (at least that's my understanding). If that was the problem then logically the mouseover event should be broken as well since they're both bound in the same manner.

Also I fixed the broken <img> tag and deployed the site. Still not working though. Good catch. :)

Comment: Hm, it might work that way in chrome, but are you sure it is the same for firefox?

Answer (score -1):

I observed that your website loads everything properly in firefox , but not in Chrome. *That* is the reason your onClick() is not fired in Chrome. $(document).on() attaches listener to elements that are *going* to be loaded, not already loaded. If you can directly attach the listener to the `pushpin` instead of `document`, then your listener will be attached to `pushpin` after the pushpin has finished loading, and then your onClick() will be called. Check out this other SO question and the answer to it, it resolves a similar issue:

[Jquery Document.on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864683/how-to-use-jquery-document-on-on-elements-that-are-pulled-in-via-ajax)

It does not solve your whole problem, but it does narrow it down to: Your elements are not being loaded by Chrome, hence your onClick() is not fired. If you can figure out why Chrome is doing that, there's your fix. In the meanwhile, you can attach listeners to the specific ID/class of elements

Comment: click event is also firing for firefox, but it doesn't work properly.