# on change not working in nested dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hello i want to display data of business3's data according to business2's and business2's data according to business1's dropdown list but on change() of business1 i got data in response but **I didn't get second on change() in dropdown list.**

```
<!-- ajax code for first business starts here -->

            <script>
                    $(document).on('change', 'select.Business1', function(){
                           var business1 = $('select.Business1 option:selected').val();
                           alert(business1);
                           var value = $(this).val();

                           $.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                data: { business1:business1 },
                                url: '<?php echo site_url('client_area/select_business_sub_cat'); ?>',
                                success : function (data){

                                        $('#business2').empty();
                                        $('#business2').append(data);
                                }
                           });
                    });
            </script>


<!-- ajax code for first business ends here -->
```

// This script is not working.  i can't find second change event.

```
<!-- ajax code for second business starts here -->

            <script>
                    $(document).on('change','#business2',function(){
                    alert('Change Happened');
                    });
            </script>


<!-- ajax code for second business ends here -->
```

I have tried with live() method also so alert called on first dropdown selection and then the ajax request calls so second drop down fills (Alternate for second script) ,

```
<script>
                   $(document).live('change', '#business2', function() {
                      alert('Change Happened');
                    });
</script>
```

Model function

```
public function select_business_sub_cat()
    {
        $business1 = $this->input->post('business1');
        $result_sub_cat1 = $this->db->query("select category.id,subcategory.* From category LEFT JOIN subcategory ON category.id = subcategory.category_id where category.id = '$business1'");
        $row_cat1 = $result_sub_cat1->result();

        $data = array(
            'id' => $row_cat1['0']->id,
            'name' => $row_cat1['0']->name
            );
        echo "<option value='" . $row_cat1['0']->id . "'>" . $row_cat1['0']->name . "</option>"; 
        // return $this->output->set_output($data);  
    }
```

View  --

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Business 1</label>
                                <select name="txtBusiness1" id="" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business1">
                                                 <option value=""> Select Business </option>
                                                 <?php 
                                                 $result_cat1 =  $this->db->query("select * from category");
                                                 $row_cat1 = $result_cat1->result();
                                                 ?>
                                                <?php foreach($row_cat1 as $item){ ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                </select>                        
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Business 2</label>
                                <select name="txtBusiness2" id="business2" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business2">
                                                 <option value=""> Select Business2 </option>
                                </select>                        
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Business 3</label>
                                <select name="txtBusiness4" id="business3" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business3">
                                                 <option value=""> Select Business3 </option>
                                                 <?php echo $abc; ?>
                                </select>                        
                         </div>
```

Comment: Is this the problem? `sucess : function (data){` -- should be `success`. *Spelling errors are deadly when coding... : )*

Comment: sorry for that it was by mistake success spelling is proper in my code.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply ... i got first ajax response properly i didn't get second on change event of dropdown list first dropdown list is filled properly using ajax. and when i change second dropdown list the on change event is not working.

Comment: @pete. yes brother i have tried with $(document) also.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one element with that id as your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dpncmj2c/1/.  Also where do you call / bind the second script?

Comment: @pete yes brother i have only one id with business2 because second dropdown fills perfectly from database. & I called second script below first script and above html content. is it fine ?

Comment: @pete please see my edited answer with live() method from live() method script calls perfectly.

Comment: Ah right, then the answer to your question should be your version of jquery is out of date and should be upgraded.  `.live`  has been replaced by `.on` and was deprecated in jquery 1.7.  It was then made obsolete and completely removed from jquery 1.9.  I would recommend upgrading your scripts rather than using out of date functions

Comment: @pete. oh. Thank you so much for this great help i always keep this in mind it was version issue i have update my jquery and tried with onchange event & it works.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because by calling `$('#business2').html(data);` you remove  the event handlers, from jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
>   Additionally, jQuery **removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers** from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.

One option would be to use `empty` and `append` like this

```
$('#business2').empty();
$('#business2').append(data);
```

instead of `$('#business2').html(data);`

Comment: Check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864683/how-to-use-jquery-document-on-on-elements-that-are-pulled-in-via-ajax

Comment: ohk brother. so i have to tried with class name ??? i didn't get exactly.

Comment: @M.I. I read this question & tried with live() method but it's not working for me.

Comment: ohk thank you for the reply i made it according to your instruction.  but it didn't work second dropdown filled according to first dropdown's data but i didn't get any thing on second dropdown's change event.

Answer (score 0):

The Script which is not working for you !!!

```
         <script>
                $(document.body).on('change','#business2',function(){
                alert('Change Happened');
                });
        </script>
```

Try this in place of the above script :

```
$(document).on("change", "#business2", function(){
   alert('Change Happened');
 });
```